# sql find duplicates in one field with specific string values in another field

Tags: sql, firebird

My question is how to make a SQL query to find duplicated records of order id that has in it product description with the string "aaa" or "bbb" for example. The desired output:

```
order_id   product_description
8899667    aaa
8899667    bbb
8866352    aaa
8866352    bbb
```

**The main problem is that I need to get the product_description tha has aaa or bbb on the string and also have the same order_ID. I hope this clarify.**

Appreciate any help on the matter.

Answer (score 0):

"find" is ambiguous - are you wanting to output as you've shown?  if so:

`select order_id,product_description from table order by order_id,product_description`

will get you what you want.  If instead you want to get a count of duplicates, something like this is probably helpful:

```
select order_id,count(distinct product_description) as duplicates from table group by order_id order by order_id,duplicates desc
```

Without more info I can't help you more.  HTH

Answer (score 0):

You can take a `COUNT(*)` for each `ORDER_ID` and pick those that have the count > 1. The `WHERE` condition takes care of `aaa` or `bbb` filter values.

```
SELECT ORDER_ID
FROM
YOUR_TABLE
WHERE  (PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION like '%aaa%' 
        OR PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION like '%bbb%')
GROUP BY ORDER_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Hello Vashi just like I have replied to kc2018 ,  I want records that have '%aaa%' or '%bbb%' that share the same ORDER_ID. Using IN is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Records with same ORDER_ID and PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION contains 'aaa' or 'bbb':

```
SELECT * FROM
YOUR_TABLE
WHERE ORDER_ID IN 
(SELECT ORDER_ID
 FROM
 YOUR_TABLE
 GROUP BY ORDER_ID
 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
AND (  PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION like '%aaa%' 
    OR PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION like '%bbb%');
```

Records with PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION containing 'aaa' or 'bbb' that share the same ORDER_ID:

```
 SELECT ORDER_ID
 FROM
 YOUR_TABLE
 WHERE
    (  PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION like '%aaa%' 
    OR PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION like '%bbb%')
 GROUP BY ORDER_ID
 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Hello , I tried your solution and it partially gave me the answer I need, but the problem is that I want records that have '%aaa%' or '%bbb%' that share the same ORDER_ID. I am using % now because the string should contain aaa o bbb but not exactly be this characters. thanks

Comment: The revised query will find the duplicates (records with same Order_ID) with the product_description field containing the string 'aaa' or 'bbb'.  If the duplicates you are looking for are records with same Order_ID and product_description containing 'aaa' or 'bbb', the product_description criteria would need to be moved inside the subquery.  See modified answer

Answer (score 0):

try this bro..it gives you the required answer:

```
 SELECT YourTable.order_id,
          YourTable.product_description
  FROM   YourTable
  JOIN   (SELECT  order_id
          FROM  YourTable
          GROUP BY order_id
          HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)             AS DuplicateRecords
  ON            (YourTable.order_id        =      DuplicateRecords.order_id)
  ORDER   BY YourTable.order_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using this:

select * from (
select order_id,list(product_description) ProdDesc
from tbl
group by order_id
) TempTable where TempTable.ProdDesc like '%aaa%'
and TempTable.ProdDesc like '%bbb%'